# master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs - how to get last run outcome

Tags: sql-server

How can I get Last run outcome with master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs

```
CREATE TABLE #enum_job
(
  Job_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
  Last_Run_Date INT,
  Last_Run_Time INT,
  Next_Run_Date INT,
  Next_Run_Time INT,
  Next_Run_Schedule_ID INT,
  Requested_To_Run INT,
  Request_Source INT,
  Request_Source_ID VARCHAR(100),
  Running INT,
  Current_Step INT,
  Current_Retry_Attempt INT,
  State INT
)
INSERT  INTO #enum_job
    EXEC master.dbo.xp_sqlagent_enum_jobs 1, garbage
SELECT  *
FROM    #enum_job
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear and you don't say which version of MSSQL you have, but assuming that you want to find the most recent job result for each job then you can simply query the job tables directly:

```
select 
    j.name as 'Job', jh.run_status as 'Result of last run'
from 
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
    join msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh
    on j.job_id = jh.job_id
where 
    jh.step_id = 0 and
    jh.run_date = (select max(run_date) from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory where job_id = jh.job_id) and
    jh.run_time = (select max(run_time) from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory where job_id = jh.job_id and run_date = jh.run_date)
```

See the documentation for `sysjobhistory` for a list of run_status values. The job tables store date and time separately as integers, so if you do a lot of querying then you might want to write a function to convert a (`run_date, run_time`) pair to a single `datetime` value. In general, querying job information from TSQL isn't as easy as it should be, so you might consider using Smo instead.